# Check integer is bit rotation of another integer

Tags: java, c++, rotation, bit-manipulation

Given two integers a and b, how can we check that b is a rotated version of a?

For example if I have `a = 0x01020304` (in binary `0000 0001 0000 0010 0000 0011 0000 0100`), then the following b values are correct:

- ...
- `0x4080C1` (right-rotated by 2)
- `0x810182` (right-rotated by 1)
- `0x2040608` (left-rotated by 1)
- `0x4080C10` (left-rotated by 2)
- ...

Comment: I wonder if there is any solution, other than actually rotating the original value and check for a match. :/

Comment: Just 32 times loop (32 bit in your case) and check for a match.

Comment: I have no idea how much this would help speed things up, but you could try and use the [POPCNT compiler intrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231(v=vs.90).aspx) to count the _number of bits_ of `a` and `b`, respectively. If the numbers differ, the answer must be `false`. Otherwise you do the full check for all possible rotations.

Comment: This is hard because rotation is not a mathematical operation, unlike shift (which is a multiply or divide by power of two)

Comment: I'm still waiting for someone to post an answer based on polynomial division :)

Comment: pop count might be an usefull optimization if cpu implements that instruction, aka break immediately if number of ones in 2 numbers dont match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, without string conversion and assuming 32 bits int:

```
void test(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
  unsigned long long aa = a | ((unsigned long long)a<<32);
  while(aa>=b)
  {
    if (unsigned(aa) == b) return true;
    aa>>=1;
  }
return false;
}
```

Comment: It seems this one is the best answer. A little update to include b in the parameter. Thanks

Comment: Just some small notes: (1) It should rather be `unsigned long long`, shouldn't it? (2) The type of a shift expression is that of the left operand, so you should rather cast the `a` in there to `unsigned long long`, just using `32LL` is not enough.

Comment: You can eventually test if(unsigned(aa)==a) return false; because of symetry, some numbers have less than 32 different rotations, like 0xAAAAAAAA, though I don't know if it will statistically fast up or slow down

Comment: Or just do {...} while( unsigned(aa)!=a); it will iterate 32 times at most, sometimes less.

Answer (score 6):

For n bit numbers you can use [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to search b inside two copies of a with complexity O(n).

Answer (score 4):

i think you have to do it in a loop (c++):

```
// rotate function
inline int rot(int x, int rot) {
   return (x >> rot) | (x << sizeof(int)*8 - rot));
}

int a = 0x01020304;
int b = 0x4080C1;
bool result = false;

for( int i=0; i < sizeof(int)*8 && !result; i++) if(a == rot(b,i)) result = true;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the same a and b. You should start loop from i=0.

Comment: Fist of all I'd rather use `unsigned int`s for any reasonable bit manipulation, then `CHAR_BIT` would be a bit better fit than `8` (or just `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits` instead of the whole `sizeof` madness), but Ok, those are just minor flaws. In general this is probably the best approach still.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case (assuming arbitrary-length integers), the naive solution of consisting each rotation is O(n^2).

But what you're effectively doing is a correlation. And you can do a correlation in O(n log n) time by [going via the frequency domain using an FFT](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms).

This won't help much for length-32 integers though.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Could you be more specific??

Comment: It's wrong, though: considering each rotation is only O(N). You rotate a to match b, but b itself isn't rotated.

Comment: @MSalters: There are O(N) rotations and comparisons, but each comparison is also O(N).

Comment: I think this is one of the cases where talking about complexity is useless. If the question was about BigIntegers I would side with you. However in this case the CPU doesn't compare bit by bit so the O(N^2) seems a bit misleading to me.

Comment: @HonzaBrabec: I see what you mean, but the reason I posted this general response is because the OP specifically said "integers" rather than "`ints`"; I may have been reading too much into that though...

Answer (score 1):

By deriving the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553522/interview-question-check-if-one-string-is-a-rotation-of-other-string), the following method (written in C#, but shall be similar in Java) shall do the checking:

```
public static int checkBitRotation(int a, int b) {
    string strA = Convert.ToString(a, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
    string strB = Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
    return (strA + strA).IndexOf(strB);
}
```

If the return value is -1, b is not rotated version of a. Otherwise, b is rotated version of a.

Comment: Meh, before converting the whole thing into strings and doing a string search, I'd rather execute that simple integer bit shift loop 32 times.

Comment: +1 for a neat trick I wouldn't have thought of.  Probably slower than just brute forcing it, but still neat.

Comment: you can use `std::bitset<32>::to_string()`, not much to it.

Answer (score 1):

If `a` or `b` is a constant (or loop-constant), you can precompute all rotations and sort them, and then do a binary search with the one that isn't a constant as key. That's fewer steps, but the steps are slower in practice (binary search is commonly implemented with a badly-predicted branch), so it might not be better.

In the case that it's really a constant, not a loop-constant, there are some more tricks:

- if `a` is 0 or -1, it's trivial
- if `a` has only 1 bit set, you can do the test like `b != 0 && (b & (b - 1)) == 0`
- if `a` has 2 bits set, you can do the test like `ror(b, tzcnt(b)) == ror(a, tzcnt(a))`
- if `a` has only one contiguous group of set bits, you can use

  ```
  int x = ror(b, tzcnt(b));
  int y = ror(x, tzcnt(~x));
  const int a1 = ror(a, tzcnt(a));     // probably won't compile
  const int a2 = ror(a1, tzcnt(~a1));  // but you get the idea
  return y == a2;
  ```
- if many rotations of `a` are the same, you may be able to use that to skip certain rotations instead of testing them all, for example if `a == 0xAAAAAAAA`, the test can be `b == a || (b << 1) == a`
- you can compare to the smallest and biggest rotations of the constant for a quick pre-test, in addition to the `popcnt` test.

Of course, as I said in the beginning, none of this applies when `a` and `b` are both variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Integer.rotateLeft` or `rotateRight` func

```
static boolean isRotation(int a, int b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if (Integer.rotateLeft(a, i) == b) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're only doing 30 tests out of the 32 possible values. While it's arguable whether `x == y` means no rotation, you're still missing at least one case.

Comment: well, on the other hand then b is not a rotated version of a

Comment: Which is why I said it was arguable. But you **still** miss the 31th rotation, even if you consider the 0th (aka. 32th) rotation should return false.

Comment: I agree, that's a bug, fixed

Comment: input is a and b, but you check x and y?

Comment: I mean isRotation(int a, int b) vs (Integer.rotateLeft(x, i) == y)