# How to generalize my algorithm to detect if one string is a rotation of another

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

So I've been going through various problems to review for upcoming interviews and one I encountered is determining whether two strings are rotations of each other. Obviously, I'm hardly the first person to solve this problem. In fact, I did discover that my idea for solving this seems similar to the approach taken in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553522/interview-question-check-if-one-string-is-a-rotation-of-other-string).

Full disclosure: I do have a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075186/beginner-question-algebraic-properties-of-string-rotations) on Math SE that's focused on the properties from a more mathematical perspective (although it's worth noting that the way that I tried to formulate the ideas behind this there end up being incorrect for reasons that are explained there).

Here's the idea (and this is similar to the approach taken in the linked question): suppose you have a string `abcd` and the rotation `cdab`. Clearly, both `cd` and `ab` are substrings of `cdab`, but if you concatenate them together you get `abcd`.

So basically, a rotation simply entails moving a substring from the end of the string to the beginning (e.g. we constructed `cdab` from `abcd` by moving `cd` from the end of the string to the beginning of the string).

I came up with an approach that works in a very restricted case (if both of the substrings consist of consecutive letters, like they do in the example there), but it fails otherwise (and I give an example of passing and failing cases and inputs/outputs below the code). I'm trying to figure out if it's possible (or even worthwhile) to try to fix it to work in the general case.

```
    public bool AreRotations(string a, string b)
    {
        if (a == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
        else if (b == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
        else if (a.Trim().Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("a is empty or consists only of whitespace");
        else if (b.Trim().Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("b is empty or consists only of whitespace");

        // Obviously, if the strings are of different lengths, they can't possibly be rotations of each other
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;

        int[] rotationLengths = new int[a.Length];

        /* For rotations of length -2, -2, -2, 2, 2, 2, the distinct rotation lengths are -2, 2
         * 
         * In the example I give below of a non-working input, this contains -16, -23, 16, 23
         * 
         * On the face of it, that would seem like a useful pattern, but it seems like this
         * could quickly get out of hand as I discover more edge cases
         */
        List<int> distinctRotationLengths = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            rotationLengths[i] = a[i] - b[i];

            if (i == 0)
                distinctRotationLengths.Add(rotationLengths[0]);
            else if (rotationLengths[i] != rotationLengths[i - 1])
            {
                distinctRotationLengths.Add(rotationLengths[i]);
            }
        }

        return distinctRotationLengths.Count == 2;
    }
```

And now for the sample inputs/outputs:

```
        StringIsRotation rot = new StringIsRotation();

        // This is the case that doesn't work right - it gives "false" instead of "true"
        bool success = rot.AreRotations("acqz", "qzac");

        // True
        success = rot.AreRotations("abcdef", "cdefab");

        // True
        success = rot.AreRotations("ablm", "lmab");

        // False, but should be true - this is another illustration of the bug
        success = rot.AreRotations("baby", "byba");

        // True
        success = rot.AreRotations("abcdef", "defabc");

        //True
        success = rot.AreRotations("abcd", "cdab");

        // True
        success = rot.AreRotations("abc", "cab");

        // False
        success = rot.AreRotations("abcd", "acbd");

        // This is an odd situation - right now it returns "false" but you could
        // argue about whether that's correct
        success = rot.AreRotations("abcd", "abcd");
```

Is it possible/worthwhile to salvage this approach and have it still be O(n), or should I just go with one of the approaches described in the post I linked to? (Note that this isn't actually production code or homework, it's purely for my own learning).

**Edit:** For further clarification based on the comments, there are actually two questions here - first, is this algorithm fixable? Secondly, is it even *worth* fixing it (or should I just try another approach like one described in the answers or the other question I linked to)? I thought of a few potential fixes but they all involved either inelegant special-case reasoning or making this algorithm O(n^2), both of which would kill the point of the algorithm in the first place.

Comment: Can you just order all characters in both strings alphabetically and compare them?

Comment: @apocalypse All rotations are anagrams, but not all anagrams are rotations. In string rotations, order matters.

Comment: In your example you have `success = rot.AreRotations("abcd", "cdab");
` = true and false! Also what exactly are you asking? To fix your algorithm, or what is the best algorithm for this?

Comment: I don't understand, why is rot.AreRotations("baby", "byba") False? Its rotated 2 spots.

Comment: @user3589054 Sorry about the confusion, that's actually an illustration of the bug, I'll clarify the comment

Comment: @S.Pinkus You're correct, apparently I was really tired when I wrote this, I edited - it's true (as it  should be). My question is two parts - first, is this algorithm "fixable?" Second, is it even *worth* fixing, or should I just try a different approach (like one described in the answers or in the other question I link to)? A few of the potential fixes I thought of would either entail lots of inelegant special-case reasoning or would make the algorithm O(n^2), both of which would kill the point of having the algorithm in the first place. I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let suppose the first string is S and the second is S', clearly if they have different length then we output they are not a rotation of each other. Create a string S''=SS. In fact concatenation of S to itself. Then if S,S' are rotation of each other we find a substring S' in S'' by [KMP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) Algorithm in `O(n)`, otherwise we output they are not a rotation of each other. BTW if you are looking for a fast practical algorithm then instead of KMP use Boyer Moore algorithm.

To address the question more explicit, I'd say that I don't expect an easy algorithm for this special case of string matching problem. So having this background in mind, I don't think an easy modification on your algorithm can work. In fact the field of string matching algorithms is very well developed. If there is a somewhat simpler algorithm than sth like KMP or suffix tree based algorithms, for this special case, then still I think studying those general algorithms can help.

Comment: Could you write C# code? `var s1 = "abc";    var s2 = "cba"; var result = (s1 + s1).Contains(s2);` result is `false`. Is it okay?

Comment: @StepUp,cba is not a rotation of abc. So the answer is true.

Answer (score 4):

Would something like this work?:

```
private bool IsRotation(string a, string b)
{
    if (a.Length != b.Length) { return false; }
    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (GetCharactersLooped(b, i).SequenceEqual(a))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private IEnumerable<char> GetCharactersLooped(string data, int startPos)
{
    for (int i = startPos; i < data.Length; ++i)
    {
        yield return data[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < startPos; ++i)
    {
        yield return data[i];
    }
}
```

P.S. This will return true for abcd = abcd, since you could consider it a full rotation. If this is not desired, change the start of the loop from 0 to 1 in the first function.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking just for a method that will check if a string is a rotation of another string, this is a C# implementation of the function you linked (which as far as I know is about the fastest way to solve this particular problem):

```
bool IsRotation(string a, string b)
{
    if (a == null || b == null || a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;

    return (a + a).Contains(b);
}
```

If you're asking for feedback on your algorithm, I'm not sure I understand what your algorithm is trying to do. It seems like you are trying to detect a rotation by storing the difference of the `char` values in the string and seeing if they sum to `0`? Or if the list of unique differences contains mirror pairs (pairs `(x,y)` where `x = -y`)? Or simply if the number of unique differences is even? Or something else entirely that I am missing from your description?

I'm not sure if what you're doing can be generalized, simply because it depends so heavily on the characters within the words that it may not adequately check for the order in which they are presented. And even if you could, it would be a scholarly exercise only, as the above method will be far faster and more efficient than your method could ever be.

Comment: First part of your answer is just trivial interpretation of my answer into C# code. Second part of your answer is more like a comment not part of an answer. So I think you should remove this answer and turn it to a comment.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri The first part of my answer is a C# implementation of the function OP linked to in his question. Since that question had its implementation in Java (and since your answer doesn't include code at all), I believe it is still relevant. The second part of my answer asks questions, but also addresses the question that OP asks, namely whether *his* approach to the string rotation problem could be generalized. Incidentally, *you* did not address that question at all, so if any question needs to be edited or removed, it is yours. (And for the record, no, I did not base my answer on yours.)

Comment: BTW keep in mind, never downvot out of spite! (Like what you did right now).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I didn't downvote out of spite. I was already deciding on whether or not to downvote and post a comment, and decided not to bother since with the amount of votes your answer got I would have apparently been in the minority, and I also had other things to do at the time. But your comment brought me back, so I decided to go through with something I was already contemplating doing.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri And as you can see, while I don't have nearly your reputation, I am not hurting for points myself, so I don't know where you get the impression that I am just doing this to "struggle for SO reputation". I do this because answering on SO is something I can do that allows me to teach while learning. Your first comment I merely disagreed with, but that accusation I frankly find incredibly insulting, and the fact that you made it I would say reveals more about your character than mine.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri And as long as we are talking about stuff I disagree with you on, I would say that your answer isn't nearly as helpful as you think it is. The first part merely reiterates what the linked question said. The second part goes into the subject of string searching algorithms, which is not what OP was asking about. It's poorly formatted, contains no code, and provides mostly information that, while interesting, is tangential to OP's question. It wasn't until you added the second paragraph at my suggestion that it was relevant at all in my opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131836/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-abion47).

Comment: `var s1 = "abc";    var s2 = "cba"; var result = (s1 + s1).Contains(s2);` result is `false`. Is it okay?

Comment: @StepUp Take a look at what you are trying to do. `"abc" + "abc" = "abcabc"`. Does that string contain `"cba"`?