# Check if second string is rotation of another string

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function that takes in two string parameters and check if the second parameter is a rotated version of the first string.

So the following would be the results:

`checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'lewaterbott'); // true`
`checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'bottlewater'); // true`
`checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'erbottlewat'); // true`
`checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'lewaterbottx'); // false`

I wrote the following code, but there are some edge cases that I can't seem to figure out:

```js
function checkRotationStrings(string, rotatedString) {
  let result;
  let rotationCheck
  let stringArr = string.split('');
  let rotatedStringArr = rotatedString.split('')

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
    if (rotatedString[0] === stringArr[i]) {
       result = stringArr.slice(i);
       rotationCheck = stringArr.slice(0, i).concat(result).join('');
    }
  }
  console.log(rotationCheck)
  if (rotationCheck === string){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which edge cases?

Comment: For example, I'm breaking the strings where the first letter in the rotatedString is found in the original string. Let's say it's `waterbottle` and `ttlewaterb`. The letter `t` will be found in index `2` first instead of index `7` which is where I want to slice.

Comment: `checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'erbottllewat'); // true` should be `false`

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the correction, edited the post.

Comment: I would recommend avoiding using `string` as a variable name, as it is *very* close to the [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object.

Comment: Here you have it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553522/interview-question-check-if-one-string-is-a-rotation-of-other-string

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) with `rotated` and two as parameter and check with [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```js
function checkRotationStrings(string, rotated) {
    return string.length === rotated.length && rotated.repeat(2).includes(string);
}

console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'lewaterbott'));  //  true
console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'bottlewater'));  //  true
console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'erbottllewat')); // false
console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'lewaterbottx')); // false
console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'ttlewaterb'));   // false
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. How does `rotated + rotated` work?

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat strange solution, as it uses `some` only for the index parameter.  But each iteration in `some` simply compares two strings, one which is a rotation of the first, and the other is the second one.

```js
const checkRotationStrings = (str, rot) => 
    str.split('').some((s, i) => str.slice(i) + str.slice(0, i) == rot);

[
  ['waterbottle', 'lewaterbott'],   // true 
  ['waterbottle', 'bottlewater'],   // true 
  ['waterbottle', 'erbottllewat'],  // false  -- ORIGINAL
  ['waterbottle', 'erbottlewat'],   // true   -- CORRECTED
  ['waterbottle', 'lewaterbottx']   // false
].forEach(([s, r]) => console.log(`'${s}', '${r}': ${checkRotationStrings(s, r)}`))
```

Comment: And this reminds me how much I hate the name `some`.  It really should be `any`.  And I have no idea *why* I feel strongly about this!

Answer (score 2):

You could use substring and rotate until you find a match. Like this:

```js
function checkRotationStrings(string, rotatedString) {

  let match = false;
  for (let i = 0;
    (i < string.length - 1) & !match; i++) {

    match = rotatedString.substring(i, rotatedString.length) + rotatedString.substring(0, i) === string;

  }
  return match

}


console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'lewaterbott')); // true
console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'bottlewater')); // true 
console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'erbottlewat')); // true 
console.log(checkRotationStrings('waterbottle', 'lewaterbottx')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
    checkRotationStrings(str1: string, str2: string) {

    if (str1.length !== str2.length) {

      return false;
    } else {

      for (var i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {

        if (str2[i] === str1[0]) {

          var substring1 = str2.substring(0,i);
          var substring2 = str2.substring(i,str2.length);
          var concatWord = substring2.concat(substring1);

          if(str1 === concatWord){

            console.log(str1 + " matches " + concatWord)
            return true;

          }else{
            console.log(str1 + " not matches " + concatWord)

          }


        }

      }

      return false;

    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow questions often receive answers in the form of completely new code (and/or ideas) on how to achieve the desired result. Usually, there's at least an attempt to help the questioner with their *actual* question, which in this case seemed to ask for some help with your code (one issue at least had to do with "slicing," as you commented).

I also love to offer new code or ideas if I particularly like it so I'm only partly critical here, but the answers so far have suffered from a complete lack of relating to the question.

There's nothing wrong with how you have conceived of checking for string rotation. You just have a couple of bugs:

First, since `rotationCheck` is meant to rotate `string` in order to compare it with rotatedString, you got the string-building reversed. It should be:

```
rotationCheck = result.concat(stringArr.slice(0, i)).join('');
```

Secondly, once you've built the rotation-check, you need to compare it with `rotatedString`, not `string`. So:

```
if (rotationCheck === rotatedString){
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be late for this, but here is my solution and it include all edge cases.

```js
function checkRotation(str1,str2){
  const char0 = str1[0];
  let ind = str2.indexOf(char0);
  while(ind>-1){
    const start = str2.substring(0,ind);
    const end = str2.substring(ind,str2.length);
    if(end+start === str1){
      return true;
    }
    ind = str2.indexOf(char0,ind+1)
  }
  return false
}
console.log(checkRotation("assads","adsass"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to break it in random pieces and do different checks, you could instead do a count of the letters. This would be much simpler:

```js
const countLetters = a => Array.prototype.reduce.call(a, (r, l) => Object.assign(r, { [l]: (r[l] || 0) + 1 }), {});

function checkRotatedString(a, b) {
  const countA = countLetters(a);
  const countB = countLetters(b);
  
  return Object.keys(countA).length === Object.keys(countB).length 
    && Object.entries(countA).every(([key, value]) => value === countB[key]);
}

// Tests
[['waterbottle', 'lewaterbott'], ['waterbottle', 'bottlewater'], ['waterbottle', 'erbottlewat'], ['waterbottle', 'lewaterbottx']]
  .forEach(a => console.log(a, checkRotatedString.apply(null, a)));
```

Comment: No: `checkRotatedString('watterbotle', 'waterbottle')`

Comment: Is that even a valid comparison though. None of his examples mentioned having more/fewer letters than the original (except the invalid case).

Comment: It's the same exact letters, just arranged differently.