# How to get the website name based on whether the website supports http or https?

Tags: php, url

I have links of the following shape: `http://website.com/stuff` and `https://website.nl/stuff`. I would like to return the http/https part with the website name and domain. So for example, if I have

`https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/55823298/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-entirely-made-of-the-same-substring`

I would like to return `https://www.stackoverflow.com`.

if I have

`http://www.website.nl/questions/55823298/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-entirely-made-of-the-same-substring`

I would like to return `http://www.website.nl`

I now have this very basic code to achieve this:

```
<?php
$urlData = parse_url('https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/55823298/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-entirely-made-of-the-same-substring');
echo "https://".$urlData['host'];
```

However, I would like that the code looks at the url and decide which prefix it should be, `http` or `https`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Here is the link to the [Manual page for `parse_url()` again](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: `echo 'The scheme ' . $urlData['scheme'];`

Comment: If you do a `print_r($urlDate);` You will be able to see the complete Array and all the data that `parse_url()` provided you with broken down into nice little compartments

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: But remember, it was all in that manual just waiting for you to look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted my code based on the advice from @RiggsFolly as follows and achieved what I wanted:

```
<?php
$urlData = parse_url('http://website.nl/questions/55823298/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-entirely-made-of-the-same-substring');
echo $urlData['scheme'].'://'.$urlData['host'];
```

which returns `http://website.nl` as wished.

Answer (score -3):

Get the first five characters of the input string and then compare it if it's "https" or http:".

Quoting linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787540/how-to-get-first-5-characters-from-string):

> For [single-byte strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-byte_encoding) (e.g. US-ASCII, ISO 8859 family, etc.) use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) and for [multi-byte strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-byte_character_set) (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.) use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr):
>
> ```
>     // singlebyte strings
>     $result = substr($myStr, 0, 5);
>     // multibyte strings
>     $result = mb_substr($myStr, 0, 5);
> ```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. The question is not asking how to get a fixed number of characters from a string. It is asking how to get the first portion of the URL, including the domain name, but not the path. That is inherently not a fixed number of characters. If you are wanting to use `substr` for this purpose, then you need to also have a way of determining the number of characters you need.

Comment: @Makyen Hello  thanks for feedback, noted, I will review more carefully.

Comment: @Makyen You're right, the question of the title is not answered by this. However, the final question in the text ("However, I would like that the code looks at the url and decide which prefix it should be, http or https. How can I achieve that?") is actually answered. Nevertheless, using `$urlData['scheme']` as proposed by aardappel is the better option.

Comment: @trippeljojo Actually, no, even that part is not answered. This just shows how to get the the first few characters of the string. It doesn't show comparing it to anything. At best, this takes one step along the path that's needed to implement the functionality that is very nebulously defined by that statement.